# SQL DB2 Select only rows with data greater than 0 in the fourth and fifth decimal place

Tags: sql, db2

I have a column in a DB2 database that has a decimal(19,5). 1523.00000.

Is there a way to run a select query that only pulls rows that have a number other than 0 in the fourth and fifth place? i.e., 1.12345 not 1.12300.

I hope I'm explaining this right, and I tried searching and see a few topics that are close to this but they didn't really answer my questions, so I figured I would ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
WHERE col <> round(col, 3)
```